# JVx application log configuration war file

Tags: logging, jvx

I have a test application for JVx application framework and already bundled the application and all dependencies in a war file. The deployment (Tomcat 9) worked without any problems and my application also works.

But how is it possible to enable logging? If found some information about logging [here](https://doc.sibvisions.com/applications/configure_logging) but I don't know how to enable logging in my running application?

Created a logging.properties file with some default settings, e.g.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
.level = SEVERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your war file, add a directory

**WEB-INF/classes**

and put your **logging.properties** in this directory.
It's also possible to create the WEB-INF/classes directory in your existing installation, if re-deployment is not possible.

Your logging.properties file only logs to console. It's better to use a log file. Use following:

```
    # only file
    handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler
    
    # both, console and file
    #handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, org.apache.juli.FileHandler  
    
    # handler configuration
    
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.sibvisions.util.log.jdk.JdkLineFormatter
    
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 10000
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.count = 5
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = com.sibvisions.util.log.jdk.JdkLineFormatter
    org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = myapp.
    
    .level = SEVERE
    
    # logs persistence
    com.sibvisions.rad.persist.level = ALL
```